# Updated cURL not taking effect in PHP

Tags: debian, php-fpm, openssl, docker, curl

I have an application running through Docker, based on the [official PHP Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/).

I've extended it to update `cURL` and get it working with `nghttp2` and `openssl`, which is what I need for HTTP/2 support in my application.

However, PHP itself isn't reflecting the change, and I don't know why.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0.3-fpm

# Add sources that allow installation of unstable packages (needed for latest OpenSSL/cURL versions).
RUN echo 'deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian testing main contrib \n\
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian testing main contrib \n\
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib \n\
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib \n\
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib \n\
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib' > /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& apt-get update

# Install OpenSSL, nghttp2 and cURL (required to make HTTP/2 requests).
RUN apt-get install -y openssl nghttp2 curl

# Install other dependencies.
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring sockets zip bcmath \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install gd

# Copy custom PHP.ini
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

# Run php-fpm.
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

`curl --version` outputs:

```
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.9 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 nghttp2/1.7.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets
```

`openssl version` outputs:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016
```

However, `php -i` outputs:

```
curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.38.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => Yes
HTTP2 => No
GSSAPI => Yes
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps,     ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.1k
ZLib Version => 1.2.8
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.4.3
```

Note that `cURL Information` shows the wrong curl version number, and `HTTP2` is marked as `no`.

Any suggestions on how to get PHP to pick this up would be *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing the php-curl extension needs to be rebuilt against the newer libcurl

Comment: @DerfK The question is, given the base docker image I'm using, how is this best approached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who wonders about this in the future, I did find a way to do it in the end. I basically created my own Docker image, heavily based on the [official PHP one](https://github.com/docker-library/php), that downloaded the newer version of cURL before compiling.

It's available on [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/marklocker/php7-http2/) (for PHP 7 running via FPM, at least).